# Compilation fails after Clover instrumentation of Java 7 try-with-resources

Tags: java, instrumentation, java-7, clover, try-with-resources

I am using a simple try-with-resources statement like the following:

```
try (final CSVWriter w = new CSVWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(r.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));){
    //do stuff......
}
```

It compiles fine using a normal `javac` Ant task, but when I have Clover instrument the code first, the resultant code no longer compiles (see the compilation message included below).

[According to the docs](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CLOVER/Clover-for-Ant), this version of Clover does support Java 7. Has anyone else run across this issue or have any idea what the problem is?

**Java version:**

```
java version "1.7.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pxi3270-20110827_01)
IBM J9 VM (build 2.6, JRE 1.7.0 Linux x86-32 20110810_88604 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - R26_Java726_GA_20110810_1208_B88592
JIT  - r11_20110810_20466
GC   - R26_Java726_GA_20110810_1208_B88592
J9CL - 20110810_88604)
JCL - 20110809_01 based on Oracle 7b147
```

**Output of Ant task:**

```
compile:
     [echo] Compiling source code...
    [javac] Compiling 135 source files to /home/*********/WEB-INF/classes
   [clover] Clover Version 3.1.2, built on November 07 2011 (build-842)
   [clover] Loaded from: /home/*******/clover.jar
   [clover] Clover: Commercial License registered to *******.
   [clover] Updating existing database at '/home/********/dist/clover/clover.db'.
   [clover] Processing files at 1.7 source level.
   [clover] Clover all over. Instrumented 135 files (12 packages).
   [clover] Elapsed time = 1.597 secs. (84.534 files/sec, 12,463.369 srclines/sec)
    [javac] /tmp/clover2218935617827048125.tmp/com/****/web/DownloadService.java:232: error: illegal start of type
    [javac]                 __CLR3_1_24ae4aegwpi0zhh.R.inc(5592);try (new java.lang.AutoCloseable() {{__CLR3_1_24ae4aegwpi0zhh.R.inc(5593);}public void close(){}};CSVWriter w = new CSVWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(response.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));){
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that [using optional **trailing semicolon** to terminate resources list in *try-with-resources*](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/tl/langtools/rev/2ab47c4cd618) is not allowed with your JDK version, **[it's illegal under JSR 334](https://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/project_coin_how_to_terminate)**.

Check this [documentation](https://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/project_coin_updated_arm_spec) :

SYNTAX: The existing set of grammar productions for TryStatement in JLS §14.20 is augmented with:

```
TryStatement:
    try ResourceSpecification Block Catchesopt Finallyopt 

Supporting new grammar productions are added:

ResourceSpecification:
    ( Resources ) 
Resources:
    Resource 
    Resource ; Resources 
Resource:
    VariableModifiers Type VariableDeclaratorId = Expression 
    Expression
```

> [An implication of the combined grammar is that a try statement must have at least one of a catch clause, a finally block, and a resource specification. Furthermore, it is permissible for a try statement to have exactly one of these three components. **Note that it is illegal to have a trailing semi-colon in the resource specification**.]

Try to drop the last semicolon :

```
try (final CSVWriter w = new CSVWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(r.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"))){
//do stuff......
}
```